# Laravel Events Listeners on multiple servers via Redis

Tags: laravel, events, redis, listener

I deploy my Laravel project on multiple servers, and my balancer distributes visitors between them.

I want to organize broadcast Events via Redis (queue) and listen to Events on all servers (servers have a common redis db).

I have Event class:

```
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class BaseRedisEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public string $connection = 'redis';
    public string $queue = 'default';
    public string $channel = 'default';

    public function broadcastOn(): Channel
    {
        return new Channel($this->channel);
    }
}
```

And class Listener

```
use App\Events\Bitcoin\Address\CreatedEvent;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;

class BaseRedisListener
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function handle(BaseRedisEvent $event)
    {
        Log::debug('New Event in Redis ' . var_export($event, true));
    }
}
```

After sending the event, I want the listener to work on all servers.

```
BaseRedisEvent::dispatch();
```

An entry is added to the logs only for the server that sent the event. I want for all servers. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

No way with logging in files. You should use add custom driver to handle the logs in /config/logging.php. Keep in mind that you should implement your custom class for this. Some example and tutorial https://cylab.be/blog/144/laravel-custom-logging

Please google about laravel custom log driver.

Comment: It's not about the logs. Here the emphasis is on the way of dispatching events between servers, how to implement it?

Comment: "An entry is added to the logs only for the server that sent the event. I want for all servers." means that the problem is logging

Comment: So If I understand, you want to use both servers to listen to this event. First the listener should implements ShouldQueue and use the trait use InteractsWithQueue;. Second you should add a public $queue = 'somequeue';. After all this you should have a supervisor to run workers which will handle this queue. Both servers have to use the same REDIS server (php artisan queue:work --queue=somequeue). Your queue driver in the env file should be redis too.

Comment: Yes, i want use both server to listen this event. If I work with a shared queue, won't the event be handled by only one server (the first to take data from the queue)?